# Custom post type suddenly vanished from admin

Tags: custom-post-types

I have been running this site for past 4 years and today suddenly my custom post type disappears from the admin menu. the contents also are not displaying. Unable to find out the issue. Here is the code

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_article_type' );
function create_article_type() {
register_post_type( 'article',
array(
  'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'Article Posts' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Article' )
  ),
  'public' => true,
  'has_archive' => true,
  'taxonomies' => array('post_category'),
  'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
)
);
}

function add_issuelink_metabox($postType) {
    global $post,$wpdb;

    $types = array('article','post');
    if(in_array($postType, $types)){
        add_meta_box("add_issuelink_metabox-meta", "Issue Link", "show_issuelink_metabox", $postType);
    }

}
add_action ('add_meta_boxes','add_issuelink_metabox');
function show_issuelink_metabox()
{
    global $post,$wpdb;
    $issuelink=get_post_meta($post->ID, "issuelink", 1);
?>

    Issue Link:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text"  style="width:700px" name="issuelink" id="issuelink" value="<?php echo $issuelink;?>"></input>
<?php   

}

add_action ('save_post','save_articlepost_metabox');    

function save_articlepost_metabox(){
    global $post;
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "issuelink", $_POST["issuelink"]);
}



register_taxonomy("post_category", array("article"), 
    array("hierarchical" => true,
            "label" => "Posts Category",
            "singular_label" => "Post Category", 
            "show_in_nav_menus"=>true,  

            ));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the rest of your functions still working?

Comment: well, i just checked it and found my custom sidebars are also not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have only ever seen that happen if a plugin is deactivated for some reason or if the CPT is tied to a theme and switch to a new theme.

Comment: the theme is same and no plugins were deactivated.